# Construction of a graph with diameter four.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to find graphs or classes of graphs where exactly two vertices have eccentricity four(and are pendant vertices) and rest of the vertices have eccentricity three. Vertices with ecc four are the only pendant vertices. Following family is the one satisfying the above criteria. Can anyone help in finding other graphs too. Thanks for the help[image]

Such graphs are called almost self centered graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we can extend your own example: you have indicated one vertex producing an infinite family,
but every vertex (except the pendants) can be used: if you have one "good" graph and a vertex $v$ in it
that is not a pendant, you can make a copy $v'$ and make $v'$ adjacent to all neighbors of $v$.
Then $d(v,v')=2$, the eccentrity of $v'$ is equal to the eccentrity of $v$ and other eccentricities do not change.

The conditions for a good graph imply that it must contain an induced $P_5$ with the pendants as its endpoints.
Following construction arose by considering the situation where the central vertex of this $P_5$ does not have
any other neighbors.

The construction is far from exhaustive. I doubt you will be able to find an exhaustive description
(apart from the one implied by the problem itself), because following is true: if $G$ is any graph,
then there is a good graph containing $G$ as an induced subgraph (when you have read the answer
you will understand why).

So let $xuzvy$ be the induced $P_5$.
Let $G$ be any $U,V$-bigraph without isolated vertices and let $H$ be any graph of diameter at most 3 and without isolated vertices.
Now we create a graph by making every vertex of $U$ adjacent to $u$, every vertex of $V$ adjacent to $V$
and every vertex of $H$ adjacent to at least one vertex of $U$ and at least one vertex of $V$.

It is easy to see that the result is a good graph, by a small case analysis (let me know if you have trouble with this).
To enlarge the family even further you can add an arbitrary number of edges "inside" $U$
and ditto inside $V$.

Can you explain why these families are interesting for you? This does not look like a homework exercise, and for me they are not very interesting.